# Merging dictionaries of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, merge

I'd like to know what be the best/most pythonic way to combine two dictionaries of dictionaries.

I have two dictionaries that look like so:

```
original = {'user1': {'COL': 'green', 'ID': '234235', 'NAME': 'andy'},
            'user2': {'COL': 'blue', 'ID': '234234', 'NAME': 'john'}}

update = {'user1': {'COL': 'black', 'ID': '234235', 'NAME': 'andy'},
          'user2': {'COL': 'purple', 'SPEC': 'na'}}
```

I would like to merge them together so that values found in the `update` dictionary would update the respective values in the `original` dictionary.

```
result = {'user1': {'COL': 'black', 'ID': '234235', 'NAME': 'andy'},
          'user2': {'COL': 'purple', 'ID': '234234', 'NAME': 'john', 'SPEC': 'na'}}
```

I have tried using `collections` and `copy`, however, I end up replacing the entire value for the key.

Comment: Can `update` contain a `user` that is not in `original`?

Comment: @ekhumoro, no, update will not contain a 'user' that is not in 'original'

Comment: In that case, the [answer by @wim](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40684691/984421) is what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is just a simple for-loop:

```
for k in original:
    original[k].update(update.get(k, {}))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for k in update:
    if k in original:
            original[k].update(update[k])
    else:
            original[k] = update[k]
```

This is assuming only one level of nesting.  A deeper solution promises to be more complex.  This also mutates the dictionary `original`, which may not be the behavior you want.

Answer (score 0):

You could use double iteration if there are two levels each time:

```
for user, values in update.iteritems():
    for k, v in values.iteritems():
        original[user][k] = v
```

Answer (score 0):

You may create a nested *dict comprehension* expression to achieve it:

```
{k1: {k2: update[k1].get(k2, v2) for k2, v2 in v1.items()} for k1, v1 in original.items()}
```

which will return value:

```
{'user2': {'ID': '234234', 'NAME': 'john', 'COL': 'purple'}, 'user1': {'ID': '234235', 'NAME': 'andy', 'COL': 'black'}}
```